# Ubuntu 14.04 FTP restart

Tags: 14.04, ftp

We use a dedicated server running Ubuntu 14.04
The FTP service sometimes quits and we need to get it restarted. This means I am stuck a day or to and is unable to work with files on the server www area.

I am not a server guy at all unfortunately (hoping to learn), but when I log on server root with `putty` I guess I should be able to restart the FTP service somehow as I have root access.

Would anyone take me through the kung-fu required to restart the FTP service ?

I have tried:

```
service vsftpd restart
```

message:

```
vsftpd: unrecognized service
```

### Solution:

The server was running proftpd so got it restarted with:

```
service proftpd restart
```

The reason why FTP stopped once a week is a glitch where the log rotation tries to restart FTP before its stopped completely. Adding a sleep and retry solves this from happening.

Comment: Since you solved the issue, make an answer with that info yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package using

`sudo apt-get install vsftpd`

If you have already installed it, try

`sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install vsftpd`

Comment: Its already installed, but its not running. This has happened twice in 2 weeks.

Comment: `service vsftpd start`?

Comment: get unrecognized service vsftpd, so it must be a different ftp server then. The problem is that i dont know what ftp server is installed as we ordered a setup inkluded ftp server but no specific. Seems like i have to await support unless its a clean way to identify the installed ftp server. When im in root i can enter ftp: root@a:~# ftp -> ftp>

Answer (score 0):

OP's original solution (added as an edit to the question):

> The server was running proftpd so got it restarted with:
>
> ```
> service proftpd restart
> ```
>
> The reason why FTP stopped once a week is a glitch where the log
>   rotation tries to restart FTP before its stopped completely. Adding a
>   sleep and retry solves this from happening.